# Excel VBA - delete every 3rd and 4th column in range

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to figure out how to delete every 3rd and 4th column in range.

I know I can delete columns in range with:

`Columns("C:E").EntireColumn.Delete`

But cannot figure out how to delete only every 3rd and 4th...

Comment: "C;E" references columns 3, 4 and 5 which does not match your title.  Having deleted columns 3 and 4, column 5 becomes column 3. You either need to start on the right and move left as you delete so the column numbers have not changed or move right allowing for the column numbers having changed. How do you know the rightmost column to delete?  You can use numbers instead of letters to identify columns so a suitable for-loop can be set up easily.

Comment: Are you trying to delete every 3rd column and every 4th column (i.e. columns 3,4,6,8,9,12,15,16,18,20,21,24,etc) or the 3rd and 4th column in every group of 4 columns (i.e. columns 3,4, 7,8, 11,12, 15,16, 19,20, 23,24, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned by @YowE3K, it's not clear if the requirement is to:

1. Delete every column that is multiple of 3 or 4 (i.e. columns 3,4,6,8,9,12,15,16,18,20,21,24,etc) or
2. Delete 3rd and 4th column in every group of 4 columns (i.e. columns 3,4, 7,8, 11,12, 15,16, 19,20, 23,24, etc).

Therefore I’m providing a separated solution for each case:

These solutions delete at once all the columns within the worksheet `UsedRange` that comply with the requirements.

1.Delete every column that is multiple of 3 or 4

```
Sub Delete_Every_Column_Multiple_Of_3_or_4()
Dim rTrg As Range, iLstCol As Integer, i As Integer
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sht(1)")  'Change as required
        iLstCol = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
        For i = 1 To iLstCol
            If i <> 1 And (i Mod 3 = 0 Or i Mod 4 = 0) Then
                If rTrg Is Nothing Then
                    Set rTrg = .Columns(i)
                Else
                    Set rTrg = Union(rTrg, .Columns(i))
        End If: End If: Next
        rTrg.EntireColumn.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

2.Delete 3rd and 4th column in every group of 4 columns

```
Sub Delete_3rd_And_4th_Column_in_Every_Group_of_Four()
Dim rTrg As Range
Dim iLstCol As Integer
Dim i As Integer
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sht(2)")  'Change as required
        iLstCol = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
        For i = 1 To iLstCol
            If i Mod 4 = 0 Or i Mod 4 = 3 Then
                If rTrg Is Nothing Then
                    Set rTrg = .Columns(i)
                Else
                    Set rTrg = Union(rTrg, .Columns(i))
        End If: End If: Next
        rTrg.EntireColumn.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]
Columns before for both cases.

[image]
Columns after for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The code below deletes every 3rd and 4th column in "Sheet1" (modify the sheet's name according to your needs):

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteEvery_ThirdFourthCol()

Dim LastCol As Long
Dim Col As Long

' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
With Sheets("Sheet1")    
    ' find last column with data in row 1 > modify to your needs
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' loop columns backwards when deleting
    For Col = LastCol To 1 Step -1
        If Col Mod 3 = 0 Or Col Mod 4 = 0 Then
            .Range(.Cells(1, Col), .Cells(1, Col)).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next Col            
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I assume the OP wants to start with the first column (every third means that in everyday language), and your code may also start with the second or the third column. Morover, I don't think that all non-empty columns have to be taken into consideration but the columns of the target Range.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub DeleteEveryThirdColumn()
    Const EveryN As Long = 3
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C:F")
    Dim c As Long: For c = ((rng.Columns.Count - 1) \ EveryN) * EveryN + 1 To 1 Step -EveryN
        rng.Columns(c).Delete
    Next c
End Sub
```